# Question with 300+ upvotes nominated to be closed, is this good moderation?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I'm relatively new to the whole moderation game, and was just served with the close queue for this (4 year old) question: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Which is now nominated to be closed, because it is a duplicate of a question that was asked 1 month before. Should this be closed? Is closing such questions not something that should be countered?

[Edit]

So my question is actually threefold:

- What is the use of closing 4 year old posts based on duplicates? (I was under the impression that this was mainly a tool to point out new questions towards the right answer)
- Should quality of the answers be taken into account?
- Should all old duplicate posts be closed in favour of the duplicate that took precedence?
- Should popularity count?

Comment: Don't confuse popularity with a post being on-topic. It *is* a duplicate, of a post that predates it.

Comment: It'll still act as a sign-post to the other post, in any case.

Comment: What's the advantage of having two questions on that same topic? Wouldn't one question that has all the information be better than splitting it up into two parts?

Comment: So the idea is that the first question always takes precedence? Do the answers matter?

Comment: Looks like it's been duped in the other direction.

Comment: Ideally its "worse -> better" as the dup relationship - we want to lead them to the best question and answer.  Sometimes this also means "older -> newer".

Comment: Looks like a moderator already came through and marked the lesser traffic'd question as a duplicate (as is normally our way).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, duplicates need to be closed. We don't want multiple questions covering the same topic laying around, *especially* if they have different information. Someone could be losing out on some valuable intel if they find one or the other, but not both. The best thing we can do is direct everything to one place and make sure that one place has *all* the information.

This is why I reversed the duplicate direction for these two questions. Yes, the other question was asked first. But the newer question has six times as many votes, four times as many views, and most importantly, *a boatload more information*. Directing visitors to the other question seems like an evil prank to play on them.

Comment: Tricky one; you aren't actually redirecting anyone are you? You're in effect saying "This is great, but there are also more answers here". If you mark the original (lower votes) as the duplicate when people do visit the newer post there is no sign post to the answers in the original question; thus you are in away not giving as much information to the majority of users. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @tim.baker Yes. Anonymous visitors are automatically redirected when they encounter a duplicate.

Comment: Didn't know that. Shows I am logged in to here an awful lot

Comment: In cases like this: why not merge?

Comment: *"Someone could be losing out on some valuable intel if they find one or the other, but not both."* - Isn't this why hyperlinks were invented?